# Common way to generate entity objects for tests

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have some misunderstanding of common way to generate test data in Entity Framework based application.


In **Rails** there's an easy-to-use gem *'Factory girl'*, which particularly gives you an ability to build instances of model classes with many customisation options.
Is there is something similar in .net world that can be used in pair with entity framework? I mean building entity object in memory basing on specified rules for it's type and without hitting the database.


I looked through several data generators - *NBuilder*, *AutoFixture*, *AutoPoco*, but wasn't able to find much mentioning of them as good tools for generating entity instances, if anything.


So I assume there is another common approach to generate test data for EF, but I can't find what is it.

I know that fixtures may be used to solve the problem (and are actually used now), but it's not the solution I'm looking for.


So, my question:

is there any widely used method to get entity object from scratch (using some rules and non-determinism) for testing purposes in .net?

Comment: you can use all the tools you named in .NET. I use currently NBuilder but will switch to AutoFixture

Answer (score 0):

Yes 
It should be based on the basic rules and coding object-oriented initiatives also can much help in this way.